# "While" loop causing error while finding prime factors of a number. And can't use this program with high numbers

Tags: python, prime-factoring

Created a program to find prime factors of a natural number but i get an error:

```
multipliers = []
a = 2
value = input("Put a natural number here: ")
value = int(value)

for i in range(1, value):
    if value % i == 0:
        multipliers.append(i)

for x in multipliers:
    while a < x:
        if x % a == 0:
            multipliers.remove(x)
        else:
            a += 1

print(multipliers)
```

All I want to do here is: Get an input value, find the multipliers of a value and make a list from them, take theese multipliers 1 by 1 and try to divide by [2, 3, 4, 5...], if `a` is a multiplier of x delete it from the list and get another value from list as x and do the same.

But when I try to run this i get an error message that says

> ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list

I don't know where am I doing wrong. Can you please help me?

Comment: Thats because you're mutating the list while removing items from it.

Comment: Try making a new list consisting values you want, instead of removing items from your first list. That means reversing the condition in your second if statement and using append instead of remove

Comment: @scharette try to run this with numbers like 20

Comment: Well i tried to work with 2 lists and @Alfie 's solution on comments. They both worked. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `x` is removed from the list - then the while loop loops again and it tries to remove `x` from the list again.

To fix this add a `break` in your while loop like so:

```
for x in multipliers:
    while a < x:
        if x % a == 0:
            multipliers.remove(x)
            break
        else:
            a += 1
```

You could also replace the second for loop with a list comprehension:

```
factors = [x for x in multipliers if all(x % a != 0 for a in range(2, x))]
```

Comment: It works well but i can't use this program with the numbers like "600851475143". I don't know why. Can you please help me?

Comment: @EmreUYGUN memory error?

Comment: No, there is nothing in command line when i enter this number.

Comment: @EmreUYGUN does the program terminate?

Comment: No. there is just a blank. seems like not working with theese numbers. But I don't get it why

Comment: @EmreUYGUN using numbers like that your computer would have to loop an insane amount of times, its probably the case that it just takes a few minutes to run - experiment with it with slightly smaller numbers and see if you cans see the speed dropping off is my advice!

Comment: Get it :). There is a speed drop as you say. But i waited 5 min and nothing happened with this high num. Is there a way to get rid of this? edit: waiting more is the way to get rid of this. Thanks @Alfie

Comment: @EmreUYGUN well your program is going to slow down no matter what as you use larger numbers - the only thing you can do is look into making it more efficient! :)

Comment: @EmreUYGUN you should do some research into efficient prime number generates - there will be some interesting stuff there :)